# why @Autowired work without @Component when inside @Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, shiro

I am configuring the shiro-spring-starter.

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {
    @Bean
    public Realm realm() {
        return new UserRealm();
    }
}
```

```
\\Without @Component
public class UserRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;
}
```

UserRealm was create using "new UserRealm()",without @Component.
why the @Autowired work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `@Component` annotation is not required because you've created the `UserRealm` object as a spring bean in the `ShiroConfig` class.  Since it's a spring bean, spring will manage the object and perform the dependency injections specified by the `@Autowired` annotation.

If you didn't create the `UserRealm` object as a spring bean in the `ShiroConfig` class, you would then need the `@Component` annotation on the `UserRealm` class.  The `@Component` annotation would cause spring to automatically create an instance of the `UserRealm` class as a spring bean, assuming component scanning is enabled.

So you either don't use a `@Component` annotation and manually create spring beans in your configuration class, or use the `@Component` annotation and let spring automatically create the spring bean.  The result is the same.

Comment: Finally, I have find a better way,using constructor to inject UserMapper In UserRealm and inject UserMapper via the field in Bean realm. thanks!